# 2002 chevy silverado 1500 4.3L V6 short bed 2door soft brake

Tags: disk-brakes

I have replaced left front caliper, installed new master cylinder ,installed new power booster, and replaced all the brake pads, when not running the brake pedal is pretty stiff when I start the truck up the pedal seems to be soft and then gets hard towards the end and that's when the brakes barely stop the vehicle I have to push hard don't know what else to do. would the ABS might cause the problem I have no brake or abs warning lights

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though the entire system may not be bled properly.  The vacuum booster is fighting with the spongy feel of trapped air.

I would start with a thorough bleed, including the ABS activation (which always seems important on Chevys) and see if the problem changes.

Comment: I will bleed brakes again ,what are you meaning by activation of Abs are talking about scan tool, I do not have that particular tool on hand, any other suggestion besides the bleeding or do i need to have the Abs done with scan tool

Comment: the abs system can trap air in it or the pipes and bleeding the system **properly** is the only way to get the air out.

Comment: You can get at least some of the air of the ABS by making a few panic stops on a soft surface like grass or loose gravel. The idea is to get the ABS to activate. This doesn't remove the air but may move it towards a wheel. Then rebleed the brakes. The best option if this doesn't work is to have it towed to a shop and have it power bled.